# Why isn't my Amazon ELB working correctly with DirectorySlash On, it's redirecting to :8080 instead of :80

Tags: apache

I'm using an Amazon ELB to point to 2 webservers, with a setup like this:

> ELB: www.elb.com
>
> web server 1: 10.10.10.1:8080
>
> web server 2: 10.10.10.2:8080

The ELB is configured to forward port 80 to port 8080 and nothing else.

Each web server works just fine when accessed by it's IP and port, and the ELB works fine with one exception.  If I go to *`www.elb.com/directory`*, I would expect to get redirected to *`www.elb.com/directory/`*, since I have DirectorySlash On set.

However I'm actually getting redirected to `www.elb.com:8080/directory/`.  This obviously fails.

Any idea what I have configured incorrectly that is causing this?

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but you could enforce the directory slash via mod_rewrite, thus eliminating the adding of the port into the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.  I had accidentally left out the ServerName line in the VirtualHost in my conf file.  Things are working correctly now, but I don't really understand why missing this would cause the behavior I've described.